# query is empty when language is change using setAppLanguage in nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm using Nextjs, and when I redirect to a page(pages/search/index), I can get the query in getServerSideProps but when I change the language using setAppLanguage by importing it from `next-translate/setLanguage`, the search page is reloaded again but the query is empty in getServerSideProps and I request with an empty query inside this page. By the way, the URL is updated from `http://localhost:3000/tr/search?q=anything` to http://localhost:3000/en/search?q=anything after the language is changed

Comment: Please provide the relevant code to the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me

```
const router = useRouter()

const changeLanguage = (lang: string) => async () => {
    await router.push(router.asPath, undefined, {
      locale: lang
    })
}
```

used it instead of `setLanguage`